# Calling external program in parallel using foreach and doSNOW: How to import results?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, pbs, snow

I'm using R to call an external program in parallel on a cluster with multiple nodes and multiple cores. The external program requires three input data files and produces one output file (all files are stored in the same subfolder).
To run the program in parallel (or rather call it in a parallel fashion) I've initially used the `foreach` function together with the `doParallel` library. This works fine as long as I'm just using multiple cores on a single node.

However, I wanted to use multiple nodes with multiple cores. Therefore I modified my code accordingly to use the `doSNOW` library in conjunction with `foreach` (I tried `Rmpi` and `doMPI`, but I did not manage to run the code on multiple nodes with those libraries).
This works fine, i. e. the external program is now indeed run on multiple nodes (with multiple cores) and the cluster logfile shows, that it produces the required results. The problem I'm facing now, however, is that the external program no longer stores the results/output files on the master node/in the specified subfolder of the working directory (it did so, when I was using `doParallel`). This makes it impossible for me to import the results into R.

Indeed, if I check the content of the relevant folder it does not contain any output files, despite the logfile clearly showing that the external program ran successfully. I guess they are stored on the different nodes (?).
**What modifications do I have to make to either my `foreach` function or the way I set up my cluster, to get those files saved on the master node/in the specified subfolder in my working directory?**

Here some example R code, to showcase, what I'm doing:

```
# #Set working directory in non-interactive mode
setwd(system("pwd", intern = T))


# #Load some libraries
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


# ####Parallel tasks####
# #Create doSNOW cluster for parallel tasks
library(doSNOW)
nCoresPerNode <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv("PBS_NUM_PPN"))
nodeNames <- system("cat $PBS_NODEFILE | uniq", intern=TRUE)
machines <- rep(nodeNames, each = nCoresPerNode)
cl <- makeCluster(machines, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

# #How many workers are we using?
getDoParWorkers()

#####DUMMY CODE#####
# #The following 3 lines of code are just dummy code: 
# #The idea is to create input files for the external program "myprogram"
external_Command_Script.cmd # #command file necessary for external program "myprogram" to run
startdata # #some input data for "myprogram"
enddata # #additional input data for "myprogram"
####DUMMY CODE######


# #Write necessary command and data files for external program: THIS WORKS!
for(i in 1:100)){
  write(external_Command_Script.cmd[[i]], file=paste("./mysubfolder/external_Command_Script.",i,".cmd", sep=""))
  write.table(startdata, file=paste("./mysubfolder/","startdata.",i,".txt", sep=""), col.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE)
  write.table(enddata, file=paste("./mysubfolder/","enddata.",i,".txt", sep=""), col.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}


# #Run external program "myprogram" in parallel: THIS WORKS!
foreach(i = 1:100)) %dopar% {
    system(paste('(cd ./mysubfolder && ',"myprogram",' ' ,"enddata.",i,".txt ", "startdata.",i,".txt", sep="",' < external_Command_Script.',i,'.cmd)'))
}



# #Import results of external program: THIS DOES NOT WORK WHEN RUN ON MULTIPLE NODES!
results <- list()
for(i in 1:100)){
    results[[i]] = read.table(paste("./mysubfolder/","enddata.txt.",i,".log.txt", sep=""), sep = "\t",  quote="\"", header = TRUE)
}

# #The import does NOT work as the files created by the external program are NOT stored on the master node/in the
# #subfolder of the working directory!
# #Instead I get the following error message:
# #sh: line 0: cd: ./mysubfolder: No such file or directory
# #Error in { : task 6 failed - "cannot open the connection"
```

My pbs script for the cluster looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# request resources:
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=8
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
module add languages/R-3.3.3-ATLAS
export PBS_O_WORKDIR="/panfs/panasas01/gely/xxxxxxx/workingdirectory"
# on compute node, change directory to 'submission directory':
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

# run your program and time it:
time Rscript ./R_script.R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**
I made a mistake: The external program is actually NOT running - I misinterpreted the log file. The reason for the external program to not run is that the subfolder (containing the necessary input data) is not found. It seems that the cluster defaults to the user directory instead of the working directory specified in the pbs submission script. This behaviour is different from clusters created with `doParallel`, which do indeed recognize the working directory. The problem is therefore solved by just adding the relative path to working directory and subfolder in the R script, i. e. `./workingdirectory/mysubfolder/` instead of just `./mysubfolder/`. Alternatively, you can also use the full path to the folder.

Comment: FYI, with TORQUE/PBS you can specify the working directory using `qsub` option `-d`, e.g. `qsub -d $(pwd) foo.pbs` will cause `foo.pbs` to be launched in the current working directory (bash syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that you look into [batchtools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=batchtools) package.  It provides methods for interacting with TORQUE / PBS from R.

If you're ok to use it's predecessor [BatchJobs](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BatchJobs) for a while, I'd also recommend to try that and when you understand how that works, look into the doFuture foreach adaptor.  This will allow you to use the future.BatchJobs package.  This combination of doFuture, future.BatchJobs, and BatchJobs allows you do everything from within R and you don't have to worry about creating temporary R scripts etc. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of both).

Example what it'll look like when you've got it set up:

```
## Tell foreach to use futures
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()

## Tell futures to use TORQUE / PBS with help from BatchJobs
library("future.BatchJobs")
plan(batchjobs_torque)
```

and then you use:

```
res <- foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% {
  my_function(pathname[i], arg1, arg2)
}
```

This will evaluate each iteration in a separate PBS job, i.e. you'll see 100 jobs added to the queue.

The future.BatchJobs vignettes have more examples and info.

UPDATE 2017-07-30: The [future.batchtools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.batchtools) package is on CRAN since May 2017. This package is now recommended over future.BatchJobs. The usage is very similar to the above, e.g. instead of `plan(batchjobs_torque)` you now use `plan(batchtools_torque)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shall have a look at it!